# How to batch extract from archive using tar to directories

Tags: command-line, osx-lion, batch, tar, archiving

I m trying to extract files contained within a directory in a tar.gz file. The extract I m using is tar zxvf foo.tar.gz. It extracts the files from the archive but removes them from the directory they are in. I want to extracted them to the directory that contains them, and want to be able to do this for multiple archives. Any help would be great!

Comment: Give it a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198151/tar-extract-into-directory-with-same-base-name).... ops a little late maybe.

Comment: Could you give an example tar file and the output you expect?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this: "_I want to extracted them to the directory that contains them_" - this is exactly what `tar` does. So there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not soure about your descption. At first list files and be soure where they are:

```
tar tvzf foo.tar.gz
```

In your question a hope, files are flat in archive without any directory.
If you want extract to any dir, make this and simple extract:

```
DIR=/any/dir/where/you/want/extract/files
mkdir -p $DIR
tar xvzf foo.tar.gz -C $DIR
```

I hope this helps. -C option cause, tar themselves move current directory to $DIR
and under this do job.

Comment: I am trying to extract the files in the folders they are contained in. I.e. In the archive there is a folder called LE71460402003130ASN00. This folder contains a series of images. I want to extract that directory with the images in it.

Comment: Or if there is not a directory called LE71460402003130ASN00 I want to create one. For each tar.gz file, with the name of the archive.